# How close is Music Fans to getting out of beta?

Tags: discussion, migration

It appears that the 'beta' status of Music Fans is the chief obstacle to migration from Music Practice & Theory. What needs to happen before graduation?

Comment: The last (mass-)graduation was [based on the site's age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708). At this point, the community and even SE staff aren't even sure about the future of the graduation process.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer to this [related question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/why-is-music-fans-still-beta), the [scoreboard on Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) gives a breakdown of the areas of improvement.

Everything is Okay or Excellent except for Number of Questions per day. Need to get up to 5 to get out of 'Unhealthy'. Currently 1.1 q/day.